# count elements in a list in two steps

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list comprised of data.frames:

```
> list1
$HSP90AB1
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     1
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$INMT
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     1

$CKB
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     1
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$NR2E1
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     0
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$ME3
             lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     0
INMT           2     1
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$FAM162A
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

$KIRREL2
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     0
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0
```

I would like to obtain the following results: first of all, sum the number of `1` there is in the column `count` of each element of the list, and then sum the number of times that the name of this element has a `1` in the rest of elements of the list, for example for `list1[[2]]`($INMT) the first step would be: 2 (there are two `1` in the `count` column), and the second step would be: 1 (there is a `1` corresponding to `INMT` in `$ME3`). A component of the list point me out through the use of `Reduce` but if I do:

```
Reduce('+', list1)
             lineNum count
HSP90AB1       7     4
INMT          14     1
CKB           21     0
NR2E1         28     1
ME3           35     1
FAM162A       42     0
KIRREL2       49     1
```

I only get the second step from what I looking for, any ideas?

Thanks

P.S there is another important question to address, in the first step only should be counted the elements that do not match the name, in my example in the first step for `$HSP90AB1` (`list1[[1]]`) only should be counted the `1` corresponding to `NR2E1` because the other `1` corresponds to `HSP90AB1` which match the name of the `list1[[1]]`.

The desired output would be the following:

```
HSP90AB1       4     
INMT           3     
CKB            2    
NR2E1          1     
ME3            2       
FAM162A        1      
KIRREL2        1
```

Here is the `dput(list1)`:

```
structure(list(HSP90AB1 = structure(list(lineNum = 1:7, count = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),
.Names = c("lineNum", "count"), row.names = c("HSP90AB1","INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3","FAM162A", "KIRREL2"), class = "data.frame"), 
INMT = structure(list(lineNum = 1:7, count = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("lineNum", "count"), row.names = c("HSP90AB1", 
"INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3", "FAM162A", "KIRREL2"), class = "data.frame"), 
CKB = structure(list(lineNum = 1:7, count = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("lineNum", "count"), row.names = c("HSP90AB1", 
"INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3", "FAM162A", "KIRREL2"), class = "data.frame"), 
NR2E1 = structure(list(lineNum = 1:7, count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("lineNum", "count"), row.names = c("HSP90AB1", 
"INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3", "FAM162A", "KIRREL2"), class = "data.frame"), 
ME3 = structure(list(lineNum = 1:7, count = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("lineNum", "count"), row.names = c("HSP90AB1", 
"INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3", "FAM162A", "KIRREL2"), class = "data.frame"), 
FAM162A = structure(list(lineNum = 1:7, count = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("lineNum", "count"), row.names = c("HSP90AB1", 
"INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3", "FAM162A", "KIRREL2"), class = "data.frame"), 
KIRREL2 = structure(list(lineNum = 1:7, count = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("lineNum", "count"), row.names = c("HSP90AB1", 
"INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3", "FAM162A", "KIRREL2"), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("HSP90AB1", "INMT", "CKB", "NR2E1", "ME3", "FAM162A", "KIRREL2"))
```

Comment: Sorry @flodel, I was trying to make things easy and clear but I was not able to, hope with this final editing my question can be understood, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. An important step is to modify your list by zeroing-out the unwanted item of each list element:

```
list2 <- Map(function(x, exclude) {x[exclude, "count"] <- 0; x},
             list1, names(list1))
```

Then you can do:

```
count1 <- sapply(list2, with, sum(count))
count2 <- Reduce(`+`, list2)$count

count1 + count2
# HSP90AB1     INMT      CKB    NR2E1      ME3  FAM162A  KIRREL2 
#        4        3        2        1        2        1        1
```

Comment: Thanks @flodel, it works perfectly fine!!, nice use of `Map`, thanks a lot